# Scylla cannot append clustering row

Tags: cql, scylla

What is the cause of the following error?

```
<IP address>:9042 replied with server error (mutation_partition::append_clustered_row():
cannot append clustering row with key {position: clustered,ckp{00024174000400000000},0}
to the partition, last clustering row is equal or greater: ckp{0002426300042d3ce7c5}),
defuncting connection.
```

It sounds like a corrupted SS table. Is this situation recoverable? Should the mutation be retried?

Comment: Which version of ScyllaDB are you using?
Did you get this error once, or repeating the query generates the same problem again?

Comment: @NadavHar'El Scylla version is 4.6.11-0.20221128.6c0825e2a. I can't reproduce this issue yet. It's a tiny fraction of all requests and not an actual problem but it sounds serious enough to find out what it means.